# How to store Dropbox files locally on my mobile device?

Tags: sync, dropbox

We all know how Dropbox works on a regular workstation. It stores the files on the disk and whenever the file is modified (or created), the software synchronizes the entire folder with the last committed folder (updating the previous files and adding the newly created files).

However this is not the case with Dropbox application for mobile devices (at least for android). The official app gives us just the interface of the folder stored on the cloud (Dropbox server). To access the files, they have to be downloaded. Changes are detected, if made; and then the files are updated.

My problem is I have to access my Dropbox files too frequently but I don't have a decent internet connection all the time. I am barely using 20-25MB of my dropbox space. The files I need to access frequently are merely some txt files of 100-200kB. I want to access them without an internet connection but whenever I update them and afterwards whenever my device finds a decent internet connectivity the files should be updated on the server.

Is there a third party application for it? Or is there any existing Dropbox feature for it, I am not aware of?

Comment: I use an app called X-plore, it has an option to sync folders.
Or as your case is specific; I recommend downloading all the txt files on a folder and then using apps like [FolderSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.full&hl=en) to sync it. Or even better, just use another cloud storage app like [Box](http://www.androidpit.com/app/com.box.android)